# Converting a bytearray into an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, integer, serialization

I am working on a program to decode MMS PDU files.  They are binary files and I am reading them byte by byte and decoding each header value as I come to it.

One header value is the Date, and it's represented as follows (in hex):

```
85 04 57 E2 A2 49
```

`0x85` is the "Date" header, `0x04` is the data length (4 bytes) and the 4 following bytes represent the date (timestamp).

I have code to read those 4 bytes and return it to me as a `bytearray`:

```
bytearray(b'W\xe2\xa2I')
```

<sub>Apparently `\x57` is a `W` and `\x49` is an `I`.</sub>

In order to parse this as a date, I need to convert it to an int.  These bytes represent the timestamp `1474470473` (or `0x57E2A249`).

I have code to convert this byte array into an int, but there has got be a better way to do it than the way I came up with.

```
timestamp = int(''.join(map(hex, byte_range)).replace('0x', ''), 16)
value = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

That is, I am converting every byte to a string (like `"0x57"`), joining them together, removing the `"0x"s`, then reading that string as a base 16 value.  This works, but it seems a little too convoluted.

I then realized that I could replace the `join`/`map` with `binascii.hexlify`, so now my code is:

```
timestamp = int(binascii.hexlify(byte_range), 16)
value = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

Like I said, this code works, but I just feel there's a better way to do this than to convert the bytearray into a string and then parse that string back as a base-16 int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To decode binary data, use [`struct.unpack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack).

```
>>> import struct
>>> byte_range = bytearray(b'\x85W\xe2\xa2I')
>>> date_header, timestamp = struct.unpack('>BL', byte_range)
>>> date_header
133
>>> timestamp
1474470473
```

Comment: `unpack` seems to be exactly what I want.  I've never really known how to use it, unfortunately.  `timestamp = struct.unpack('>L', byte_range)` gives me the value I expect.